# XPath Filtering with xsl:key() function

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslkey

I am trying to compare two xmls based on some node value.

Below are the two xmls:

**a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <Test>a</Test>
        <Test1>aa</Test1>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <Test>e</Test>
        <Test1>ee</Test1>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <Test>f</Test>
        <Test1>ff</Test1>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <Test>c</Test>
        <Test1>cc</Test1>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

**b.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <Test>a</Test>
        <Test1>aa</Test1>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <Test>b</Test>
        <Test1>bb</Test1>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <Test>c</Test>
        <Test1>cc</Test1>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

I am trying to compare the xmls using the content of **Test** as key.

Below is the xsl that I am using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="cd" match="cd" use="Test"/>
    <xsl:template match="/catalog">
        <!-- This is working -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="cd[Test=document('a.xml')/catalog/cd/Test]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <!--This is not working-->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="cd[Test=key('cd', cd/Test, document('a.xml'))/Test]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <!--This is returning node-set-->
        <xsl:message>
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('a.xml')/catalog/cd/Test"/>
        </xsl:message>
        <!--This is returning node-set-->
        <xsl:message>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('cd', cd/Test, document('a.xml'))/Test"/>
        </xsl:message>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output of the xsl should be common nodes in both xmls, based on **Test** node value.

But not sure why the one using xsl:key() function is not working. When I print it separately it is showing the correct node-set.

Comment: Is it because it should be `<xsl:copy-of select="cd[Test=key('cd', Test, document('a.xml'))/Test]"/>`, or maybe just `<xsl:copy-of select="cd[key('cd', Test, document('a.xml'))]"/>`?

Answer (score 2):

That behavior is explained because of those XPath/XSLT expressions in the context of `catalog` element:

1. Without key: `cd[Test=document('a.xml')/catalog/cd/Test]`

Here you are going to select `cd` elements filtered by the predicate:

> any of my `Test` childs has a string value equal to any of those
>   `Test` elements in `a.xml` document

2. With key: `cd[Test=key('cd', cd/Test, document('a.xml'))/Test]`

Here you are going to select `cd` elements filtered by the predicate:

> any of my `Test` childs has a string value equal to any of those
>   `Test` childs of the nodes that result from invoking the key named `cd` in 
>   the context of `a.xml` document with the string value of **all my grandsons 
>   `Test` of all my childs `cd`**

That last part will be an empty node set evaluated from the context of any `cd` element.